# Why is the operator norm $||T||_{op} = \text{sup}\{\frac{||Tv||}{||v||} = \text{sup}\{||Tv|| : ||v|| \leq 1\}$

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Is this just coming from the fact that $||Tv|| \leq R||v|| \underset{||v|| \leq 1}{\leq} R$? and then just taking the sup? If so (or if not) I can't seem to wrap my head round this. Thank you!

Comment: Is $T$ a linear operator? Did you mean $\sup \{\|Tv\| / \|v\| \mid v\neq 0\}$ ?

Comment: T is linear. No i did not mean that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V \neq \{ 0 \}$ and $W$ be normed spaces, and let $T \colon V \to W$ be a linear operator.
Then
$$ \sup_{v \neq 0} \frac{\| T v \|}{\| v \|} = \sup_{v \neq 0} \Bigl\| T \frac{v}{\| v \|} \Bigr\| = \sup_{\| y \| = 1} \| T y \|. $$
So if we look at the size of the output divided by the size of the input for *all possible* input (except zero, but we know that $T 0 = 0$ by linearity), we get just the same thing as if we only looked at the images of size 1 inputs.

Now it is also true that
$$ \sup_{\| y \| = 1} \| T y \| = \sup_{\| y \| \leq 1} \| T y \|. $$
To see this, note that
$$ \sup_{\| y \| = 1} \| T y \| \leq \sup_{\| y \| \leq 1} \| T y \| $$
is obvious (the right-hand side is taking sup over *more* things), and if $\| y \| \leq 1$, then $y / \| y \|$ is of size 1, so
$$ \| T y \| = \| y \| \Bigl \| T \frac{y}{\| y \|} \Bigr \| \leq \Bigl \| T \frac{y}{\| y \|} \Bigr \| $$
where the right-hand side is now the image of a size 1 input.
Now take sups over $\| y \| \leq 1$ of both sides to get
$$ \sup_{\| y \| \leq 1} \| T y \| \leq \sup_{\| y \| = 1} \| T y \|. $$

Comment: Thank you that helps

Answer (score 1):

Since $T$ is linear, take any $v\neq 0$, since it holds that
$$
\frac{\|T v\|}{\|v\|} = \bigg\| T\bigg(\frac{v}{\|v\|}\bigg)\bigg\|,\quad \text{and}\quad \left\|\frac{v}{\|v\|}\right\| = 1
$$
You can directly see that
$$
\sup\left\{\frac{\|Tv\|}{\|v\|}\right\} = \sup\big\{\|Tv\|\mid \|v\| = 1\big\}
$$

By the same reasoning you can reduce
$$
\sup\big\{ \|Tv\| \mid \|v\|\leq 1\big\} = \sup\big\{\|Tv\| \mid \|v\| = 1\big\}
$$
This shows that the three formulations are equivalent
$$
\|T\| =\sup\left\{\frac{\|Tv\|}{\|v\|}\right\} = \sup\big\{ \|Tv\| \mid \|v\|\leq 1\big\} = \sup\big\{\|Tv\| \mid \|v\| = 1\big\}
$$

Edit:
This hold if we assume that the vector space we work on is not trivial, i.e. $V\neq \{0\}$.